# Sending Emails with SendGrid and Rails API from React App

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, sendgrid, rails-api

I have an app built with React that uses a Rails API to send SendGrid emails. I have been getting errors / missed emails during some (but not all) submissions and wasn't sure if I had set it up properly. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

The desired functionality is:

1. Create a Lead off of the submitted form from React
2. Send a SendGrid email with the Lead information to all the Venues
3. Send a SendGrid email to the person who filled out the email

I've attached the related file parts below, hopefully this is enough to help get me started on a fix. Thanks!

*form.js*

```
...
handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    let lead = this.buildFormObj()

    window
        .fetch('/api/leads', {
            method: 'POST',
            body: JSON.stringify({ lead }),
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            }
        })
        .then(resp => resp.json())
        .then((json) => {
            console.log(json)
        })
        .catch(err => console.log(err))
}
...
```

*config/environment.rb*

```
...
ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
  user_name: ENV['SG_USERNAME'],
  password: ENV['SG_PASSWORD'],
  domain: "website.com",
  address: "smtp.sendgrid.net",
  port: 587,
  authentication: :plain,
  enable_starttls_auto: true
}
```

*leads_controller.rb*

```
...
def create
  @lead = Lead.new(lead_params)
  if @lead.save
    @venues = Venue.all
    @venues.each do |venue|
      if venue.email
        UserNotifierMailer.send_lead_email(venue, @lead).deliver
      end
    end
    UserNotifierMailer.send_signup_email(@lead).deliver
    render json: @lead, status: :created, location: @lead
  else
    render json: @lead.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
  end
end
...
```

*user_notifier_mailer.rb*

```
class UserNotifierMailer < ApplicationMailer

  default from: '"Email Name" <email@website.com>'

  def send_signup_email(lead)
    @lead = lead
    if @lead.email
        mail(to: @lead.email, subject: 'Thanks for submitting!')
    end
  end

  def send_lead_email(venue, lead)
    @lead = lead
    @venue = venue
    if @venue.email 
        mail(to: @venue.email, subject: 'New Lead Created')
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: have you tried triggering an email? did it work?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by 'triggering' but it successfully sends some of the emails - but sometimes gets hung up